# Symfony - entity inheritance and form

Tags: symfony

In my project I have an abstract entity, let's call it Parent, and two child entities: ChildA and ChildB that extend Parent class. I'm using doctrine and a single table strategy, has ChildA and ChildB are similiar. This part is working ok, now my problem is with the form.

I want to have a single form that can be used to create an entity of one of those classes (ChildA or ChildB), so I want to have a first field in the form to select which kind of entity the user wants to create, and show the fields for that class (has there are only one different field, I'm using javascript to show/hide the field according to the selected class)

To accomplish this I have created a form with all the fields of both ChildA and ChildB plus the field to select the type, and my idea was in controller check the type, and then create a specific form associated with ChildA or ChildB according to the selected type, and bind it with the valus received from the main form, but the problem here is how to display the errors in this form

Anyone have a good solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think you make it very difficult this way.
For this problem i would create 2 forms (FormChildA, FormChildB) with the associated fields accordingly.
Because you are using javascript anyway, just render the page with a choice and get the form with ajax:

```
<div id="select-type">
    <button value="child_a" type="button">Select ChildA</button>
    <button value="child_b" type="button">Select ChildB</button>
</div>
<div id="form-container"></div>
<script>
    $('#select-type button').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.get('path/to/get_ajax_form', {type: $(this).val()}, function(data) {
            $('#form-container').html(data);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Create a Controller method to retrieve the form:

```
public function getAjaxFormAction()
{
    $type = $this->get('request')->query->get('type');
    switch( $type ) {
        case 'child_a':
            $form = $this->createForm(new FormChildA, new ChildA);
            break;
        case 'child_b':
            $form = $this->createForm(new FormChildB, new ChildB);
            break;
    }

    return $this->render('AcmeBundle:Forms:_type_form.html.twig', array(
       'form' => $form->createView(),
       'type' => $type,
    ));
}
```

Add to each form a hidden field with the form type value,
this way you can validate these forms in one method (same way as you retrieve them).

This makes it easier to modify and validate each form separately!

Comment: You are right about the simplicity. I only see a possible problem in this approach, if the user change the type after have the form filled, he have to fill the form again, but still, I think I will follow this approach, thanks for the idea

Comment: No problem, you're right about the change form problem. But maybe this can be solved with the use of [sisyphus.js](http://simsalabim.github.com/sisyphus/). If you give the equal fields the same name you can update your form with sisyphus each time the user selects the other form. (just an idea)